# jqm: Footer and header reamoved when list item clicked

Tags: jquery-mobile, sticky-footer

I have programmed a shopping list. The footer contains buttons for actions on a selected item in the list and I defined the footer as fixed so that it is always visible in the screen.

Now that I'm testing with an item list longer than the screen in firefox I discover that if I click on an item in the list (select it), the header and footer disappear from the screen and moved respectively to the top and bottom of the list. It looks as if the fixed attribute is toggled when clicking on the list.

This gets me in trouble because when I select an item in the list, the footer with the buttons disappear and I need to scroll to the end of the list to click on the buttons.

How could I remove this behavior ? I fear that if I set the fixed attribute every time an item is clicked, that the footer and header will flicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in jQueryMobile fixed toolbars toggle when you tap on the screen. You can disable this behaviour with `$.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);`. You can see more information [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html), in the section "Tap to toggle visibility".

Comment: (Here it is)[http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html]. I'm suppose to add the attribute data-tap-toggle="false", but it also doesn't work.

Comment: The attribute must be added to the footer and header html tags. Then it works.